# React Tailwind Project Not Working Correctly in Mobile Version or Smaller Screen?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, portfolio

I'm facing a little issue in my project I'm currently working on. I created a project in **React and Tailwind**, it's working perfectly in full screen means in PC, but in smaller screen the text is **overwrite each other**. There are different sections like about, portfolio, experience etc. When I'm trying to smaller the browser screen size, the text and titles are overwriting each other.
Need Solution.
[Desktop mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy7sQ.jpg)

[Mobile mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c1tV.jpg)

[Mobile mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2PlN.jpg)

I need a solution in my project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your components responsive using Tailwind CSS breakpoints.

```
 <div className="text-[32px] md:text-[24px] "></div>
```